# output html in terminal error

Tags: python, html, lxml

I'm trying to print out html content in following way:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

url = 'http://www.amazon.co.uk/Membrane-Protectors-FujiFilm-FinePix-SL1000/dp/B00D2UVI9C/ref=pd_sim_ph_3?ie=UTF8&refRID=06BDVRBE6TT4DNRFWFVQ'
page = requests.get(url)
print page.text
```

then i execute `python print_url.py > out`, and I got the following error:

> print page.text UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode
>   character u'\xa3' in position 113525: ordinal     not in range(128)

Could anyone give me some idea? I had these problem before, but i couldn't figure it out.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your `page.txt` is not in your local encoding. Instead it is probably unicode. To print the contents of page.text you must first encode them in the encoding that stdout expects:

```
import sys
print page.text.encode(sys.stdout.encoding)
```

Comment: I got error: TypeError: encode() argument 1 must be string, not None

Comment: Why would it be None?

Answer (score 0):

The page contains non-ascii unicode characters. You may get this error if you try to print to a shell that doesn't support them, or because you are redirecting the output to a file and it's assuming an ascii encoding for output. I specify this because some shells will have no problem, while others will (my current shell/terminal defaults to `uf8` for instance)

If you want the output to be encoded as `utf8`, you should explicitly encode it:

`print page.text.encode('utf8')`

If you want it to be encoded as something the shell can handle or `ascii` with non-printable characters removed or replaced, use one of these:

`print page.text.encode(sys.stdout.encoding or "ascii", 'xmlcharrefreplace')` - replace nonprintable characters with numeric entities

`print page.text.encode(sys.stdout.encoding or "ascii", 'replace')` - replace nonprintable characters with "?"

`print page.text.encode(sys.stdout.encoding or "ascii", 'ignore')` - replace nonprintable characters with nothing (delete them)

Comment: Error:TypeError: encode() argument 1 must be string, not None

Comment: Added or "ascii". I think that's related to piping the output to a file rather than actually being on a terminal. If you really want to write it to a file, see the second solution (encode as utf-8 and open the file in your script)